# Multiple arrows orientation Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, arrow

Want to change orientation of an arrow of one object. However, when I change the orientation by the "Flip the mark horizontally" button (I don't know the name in English, just tried to translate) it changes the orientation of each arrow in the document. I was wondering how to ensure only the arrows of the selected object are changed.

[image: Before change]

[image: Wanted to switch only the arrows on the circle]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't reproduce the problem. [see screen capture here](https://imgur.com/sse16pE). What version of Inkscape are you using?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. Using Inkscape version 1.2.2. The printscreens should be there: [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AjPeWHZLHt5cgb99BKK4UJ3_zGUz4A?e=hkH8CL). The button I used is in the green circle.

Comment: I'm using 1.3 - the most recent version. Try that.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I have downloaded the v1.3 but the problem persists. I'm not able to change the direction of a single arrow.